# Is it possible to define mapping after the index creation and data loading in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an index and have indexed document in the same. Now it seems that I have forgotten to add a mapping to that index. Is it possible to add the required mapping to that index,at this point of time when the documents are indexed in it?. If not,what is my next best choice to implement the mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [PUT mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-put-mapping.html) to modify the mapping , but then its not possible to change all aspects of the mapping.
For eg: , you cant change the analyzer type , the data type of the fields  but then you can add more non existing fields and assign them analyzer.
Also if you are looking at multi fields , you can add more fields to existing multi fields , but not edit the existing. 
Having said that , if your change comes under the category of non changeable mapping , the better idea would be to reindex the documents.

Answer (score 3):

It depends but probably. If your new mapping doesn't conflict then you can use the [Put Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-put-mapping.html). In general it's safe but you can't change or remove existing fields.

You will have to re-index your documents though. You can either simply re-submit all of your documents through the API or try a [plugin](https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex) speicifically designed for this case..